# Java RegEx that matches anything BUT literal string 'NIL' or 'nil'

Tags: java, regex, null

OK, guys. Here's a Java interview-type question that seems to have stumped some very smart people around here. They actually need this for production code, so it's more than just an interview puzzler.

They need a regular expression, in Java, that returns true if a string literal is *anything* other than the 3-letter word NIL. The test needs to be case insensitive, and the RegEx itself must do all the work.

So, the RegEx should reject **NIL, nil, NiL, nIL,** and so on.

It should, however, accept: nile, anil, will, zappa-nil-a, and the empty string.

*How many Java developers does it take to write a trivial RegEx? Apparently a lot!*

Comment: +1 for that part in italics there, Armchair Bronco buddy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this using a [negative lookahead](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html&ei=GPGRT5nSHqnliAKe_YziDQ&usg=AFQjCNH50o6T1e3LK70EJqezzZTLsRPRhw&sig2=xuTvDIrwSy5vkguGMhTSSg).

With case-insensitive option enabled:

```
^(?!nil$).*
```

You could leave off the `.*` at the end if you don't need to actually return the string in the match.  Here is a version without the case-insensitive option:

```
^(?![nN][iI][lL]$).*
```

Explanation:

```
^       # start of string anchor
(?!     # start negative lookahead (fail if...)
   nil    # literal characters 'nil'
   $      # end of string
)       # end lookahead
.*      # consume string (not necessary, but it acts more like a typical regex)
```

If you want the regex to match `nil\n`, then use `\z` instead of `$` in the lookahead: `^(?!nil\z).*`

Comment: According to one of the lead devs on this burning issue, the code in your first example ^(?!nil$).* will work if modified as follows: "^(?i)(?!nil$).* Extra bit at the front is required because we don't have control over compiler options so the RegEx has to do this work itself.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. Note that we added (?i) to the front of the RegEx, just after "^"

Comment: @ArmchairBronco `Note that we added (?i)` Yes, that's why Andrew said to [enable case-insensitive matching](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#i). There are two ways to do this in Java: `(?i)` and `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a true regular expression for this, one that directly specifies a finite automaton that can be fed the characters of the string one by one and will reach an acceptance state if the string is not a variant on NIL:

```
 (|.|..|[^Nn]..|.[^Ii].|..[^Ll]|....+)
```

This will work on classic regex engines which don't implement look-around hacks, and can be converted to a blazingly fast DFA.

You may have to anchor this with `^` and `$`, depending on what kind of regex function you use this with: (whole string) match semantics, or substring search semantics.

For instance, grep test:

```
 # rejects lines like nIl and NiL but accepts all else
 # including blank lines:

 grep -E '^(|.|..|[^Nn]..|.[^Ii].|..[^Ll]|....+)$'
```

The idea here is that:

1. All strings of length one, two, or four or more match.
2. A three-character string matches if and only if:

   1. It does not begin with an N or n; or
   2. It does not have an I or i in the middle; or
   3. It does not have an L or l at the end.

How NIL and Nil are rejected is that they fail all three rules 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3. NIL does begin with an N, so it fails 2.1. It does have an I in the middle, so it fails 2.2, and it does have an L at the end so it fails 2.3.

Comment: You can put that in your "lead dev's" pipe and have him smoke it for while, haha. :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Kaz. Not sure if he smokes, but I'll make sure he gets a whiff of this new tobacco.  I appreciate the alternate approach as well as the explanation.