# Sum a range that does not contain specific word

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I would like to sum a range where a corresponding range does not contain "2nd".

Here is the opposite of what I want:

```
=sum(filter(fUsers,regexmatch(fLabel,"2nd")))
```

Which runs and returns 1,150.

I have looked at and tried to copy these SO posts:

- [Regular Expressions and negating a whole character group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977251/regular-expressions-and-negating-a-whole-character-group)
- [How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex)
- [Java RegEx that matches anything BUT literal string 'NIL' or 'nil'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254774/java-regex-that-matches-anything-but-literal-string-nil-or-nil)

I know that if I go to the data set in question and use filtering, I should have 15,017 returned.

Based on these posts here is what I have tried:

```
=sum(filter(fUsers,regexmatch(fLabel,"^(?!2nd$).*")))  // returns #N/A no matches found in filter evaluation.

=sum(filter(fUsers,regexmatch(fLabel,"^(?!.*2nd).*$")))  // returns #N/A no matches found in filter evaluation.
```

How can I get Gsheets to sum values in range fUsers where fLabel does not contain "2nd"?

Comment: Try `"^(?:(?!2nd).)*$"`.

Comment: whats your input string?

Comment: @stribizhev thanks for trying but same result: #N/A.

Comment: @karthikmanchala my environment is Google Spreadsheets with regexmatch() formula. The input is a column of string values

Comment: can you give sample value.. and what is expected out of it?

Comment: What about `=sum(filter(fUsers,NOT(regexmatch(fLabel,"2nd"))))`?

Comment: For now I have gotten around this by using not() function: sum(filter(fUsers,not(regexmatch(fLabel,"2nd")))). But would be nice to be able to use regexmatch() only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use a built-in `NOT()` operator (see [`Filter` Sample Usage](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)):

```
=sum(filter(fUsers,not(regexmatch(fLabel,"2nd"))))
```

**EDIT**:

Accoding to [RE2 regex syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt), negative look-aheads are not supported.

> (?!re)    before text not matching «re» NOT SUPPORTED

This means, you *cannot* check with a regex if *a sequence of characters* is missing in the input string. You could check if 1 symbol is missing, but not several.

Comment: It is not possible to achieve with a regex. You could check if a cell has no hyphens with `^[^-]*$`, but when you have several subsequent characters, you need a look-around. Sorry, just `NOT()` is the only Gsheet way of doing this.